# How to combine :vim and :s in vim

Tags: vim, editor

For example, i have a task to search all file under current directory where contains "foo" and then replace to "bar".
Now here is my current solution:
`:vim /bar/ **/*`
Use this to search all appearances of `foo`, and then replace it one by one to "bar"
`:s/foo/bar/gc`
Obviously it is not a good solution when replaces becomes large. So if there is a better solution to combine these two operations into one. But there is a precondition : Must give a hint before replacement just like what the `c` does in the second command. This is prevent replace some word that doesn't need to replace.

Answer (score 3):

Open all files in vim:

```
$ vim *
```

Replace `foo` with `bar`

```
:argdo %s/foo/bar/ | update
```

Tutorial: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace_in_multiple_buffers

Answer (score 0):

the easiest would be:

```
vim $(egrep -l '/foo/' **/*) -c 'bufdo %s/foo/bar/g'
```

but this will fail if there's whitespace on the filenames, a more robust approach would be:

```
files=()
while IFS= read -rd '' filename; do
    files+=("$filename")
done < <(egrep -Zl '/foo/' **/*)
vim "${files[@]}" -c 'bufdo %s/foo/bar/g'
```